# How to improve wireless network speed?

Tags: 10.04, wireless

I am running 10.04 LTS on a desktop PC with a Belkin G-Plus MIMO Wireless network card.

Ever since running Ubuntu on the machine I have noticed fairly slow network speeds (about half the speed I get when running the same card through Windows)  I did some research I found out that by and large wireless network cards aren't that well supported on most Linux distros.

I was wondering though if there is anything I could be tweaking on the system that could help squeeze a little more out of the card?

**Here is some more information**

> *-network:1
>
> ```
>    description: Wireless interface
>    physical id: 2
>    logical name: wlan0
>    serial: 00:1c:df:24:5e:54
>    capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
>    configuration: broadcast=yes ip=192.168.1.5 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bg
> ```

Comment: Cheers for the edit, looks a lot more question like now!

Comment: Is your router set for G-only or B/G Mixed?  You'll get better performance with G-only.

Comment: Good question and I will check, although would that explain why under Windows the speed is much better?

Comment: Is that the full device info? what does `sudo lshw` in a terminal say about you wifi-card? It seems like it's a Ralink card (The manufacturer of the chip isn't necessary the same as the brand that is on the box!) but i can't find any specific information about it.

Comment: @Toby my experience belkin card and routers suck. so more information might be helpful.

Comment: @Source Lab - I have edited my question with the results from the command you asked me to run. (may be of use to you too @garbagecollector)

Comment: What are you using to test the speed in each OS?

Comment: Various online speed tests but to be honest it is even just casual observation. I use Ubuntu in other environments and know it can work way better than this setup is.

Comment: What is the speed that you are getting? and how about if you just use firefox for a simple download? (you can install and use nload, `nload -u H -U H wlan0` to measure speed. Speedtest are often flash, and flash for linux is quite sluggish.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention what kernel driver you're using for the card, but often tunables can be found in /sys/module/[driver]/.  For example, my iwlagn driver shows this:

bryce@lynmouth:/sys/module/iwlagn$ ls

drivers/  holders/  initstate  notes/  parameters/  refcnt  sections/  srcversion  version
bryce@lynmouth:/sys/module/iwlagn$ ls parameters/
11n_disable    amsdu_size_8K    antenna          fw_restart4965  queues_num    swcrypto
11n_disable50  amsdu_size_8K50  disable_hw_scan  fw_restart50    queues_num50  swcrypto50

To find out some more info about what the parameters mean, look at the output of `modinfo <driver>`.

To change values of a parameter, just do "echo [number] > /sys/module/[driver]/parameters/[parameter]".  Some parameters are read-only, so do a "cat .../[parameter]" to check that your new value was set.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't ideal but can you try a different wifi card? Wifi can be really hit and miss. At least this way you can determine if a different card makes any noticeable bandwidth differences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling [Jumbo Frames](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rhel-centos-debian-ubuntu-jumbo-frames-configuration/).

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo iwconfig wlan0 rate 54M
```